# Python function returning list of tuples, instead of 2D list

Tags: python

Basically the title. Here is my code

```
def newList(nums):
    if len(nums) == 0:
        return
    if len(nums) == 1:
        return[nums[0]]
    return [nums[0], nums[-1]], newList(nums[1:-1])

print(newList([1,2,3,4,5]))
```

I'm suppose to get `[[1,5],[2,4],[3]]` but instead I'm getting a tuple -> `([1, 5], ([2, 4], [3]))`. I understand that the comma is causing this in the return function but how do I just get the list?

Comment: Why are you supposed to get that output? What's the transformation involved?

Comment: If you want to return a list, why are you returning a tuple? The fix seems obvious.

Comment: `return [nums[0], nums[-1]], newList(nums[1:-1])` is very clearly creating a tuple with two elements.

Answer (score 0):

```
def newList(nums):
    if len(nums) == 0:
        return []
    if len(nums) == 1:
        return [[nums[0]]]
    return [[nums[0], nums[-1]]] + newList(nums[1:-1])

print(newList([1,2,3,4,5]))
```

should do what you want, it just ensures that all base cases return a list of list

then just pretends the recursive case to that list, so that you end with a normal 2d list of lists in all cases

Comment: Don't just post code. Explain what they did wrong and how you fixed it.

Comment: i hit enter too soon ...

Comment: Not just the base cases, all cases.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is in the `return`. By doing

```py
return [nums[0], nums[-1]], newList(nums[1:-1])
```

you are returning a tuple of two elements.

The solution from @Joran Beasley solves the problem.

However, I suggest you not to use recursion in Python.
Your function (after fixing it) won't work for long lists.

In fact, by doing

```py
import sys
sys.getrecursionlimit()
```

you will see that a single function call can do recursion just 1000 times.
For example

```py
newList([1]*1996)
```

raised this error on my machine

```
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

I would implement your function this way instead

```py
def newList(nums):
    # add the next line if you will the original
    # list (i.e. `nums`) after calling newList
    nums = nums.copy()
    ###
    new_list = []
    while nums:
        new_item = [nums.pop(0)]
        try:
            new_item.append(nums.pop(-1))
        except IndexError:
            pass
        new_list.append(new_item)
    return new_list
```